# Get top most view controller under UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, xcode9.2

I am using below code to find the top most ViewController. If alert is presented, the code above gives UIAlertController. How do I get top view controller under UIAlertController?

```
+(UIViewController*)topMostViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController
{

    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topMostViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    }
    else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topMostViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    }
    else
    {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you using the above code, and more broadly, why are you doing this check? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer. Since you want to find the top most view controller that is visible, you can you any of these two methods. Call this method from the view controller you are currently in by passing the UINavigation controller as parameter.

```
func  topMostViewController(controller:UINavigationController) -> UIViewController {

    return controller.topViewController!

}

func  visibleViewController(controller:UINavigationController) -> UIViewController {

    return controller.visibleViewController!

}
```

Comment: I tried your idea to find the top most ViewController, but if alert is presented, the code above gives UIAlertController. How do I get top view controller under UIAlertController?

Comment: Check the following method and see the second item in the navigation stack. self.navigationController?.viewControllers

Comment: Thanks Subin. But this also not working. Can you please provide more info by considering my code as example

Comment: Thx Subin. I want to find the top most ViewController, but if alert is presented, the code above gives UIAlertController. How do I get top view controller under UIAlertController?

Comment: It worked for me. How are you presenting the alert ? Are you using UIAlertView or UIAlertController ?

Comment: I am using UIAlertController. Can you check with my code.

Comment: Did you try the code i have shared instead of your method?

Comment: For my requirement i have to check all conditions as in my code. When alert comes then my code returns UIAlertController as topmost view controller so i want  get previous top most view controller when alertController comes